# getting most popular hashtags using twitter api

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I want to retrieve top 10 or top 20 most popular hashtags from twitter api.

How can I do it, is there any direct api for this or should I collect a large dataset using twitter search api and manually collect popular hashtags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Twitter API documentation is [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/trends/trends-for-location/api-reference/get-trends-place.html).

Using Tweepy (Recommended Method) :

```
import tweepy

consumer_key ="PUT_YOUR_KEY"
consumer_secret ="PUT_YOUR_KEY"
access_token ="PUT_YOUR_KEY"
access_token_secret ="PUT_YOUR_KEY"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
tags = api.trends_place(23424848) # 23424848 Corresponds to the Yahoo ID for India. Change this to the location that you require.
```

If you do not have tweepy installed use :

```
pip install tweepy
```

Comment: Is this possible to do with V2 API or does the functionality simply not exist?